# Handling Google Instant inside Kynetx

Tags: krl

How is the Kynetx plugin triggered? Is it by the page onload event?

Google Instant is interfering with the Kynetx plugin. WebScarab shows multiple GETs to Google on a search (Instant is ON) but no calls back to cs.kobj.net.

Does Kynetx have a plan to adapt their framework to handle Google's new Instant feature? Does it already exist? I can't find very much documentation on it.

Answer (score 2):

Great question. The new search annotation functionality was completed within days of Google instant being released by Google. The in depth documentation for using the new search annotation functionality that is compatible with Google instant can be found at http://docs.kynetx.com/docs/NEW_Search_Annotation_V2.0